# Closed subgroup of $GL({\cal A})$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, group-isomorphism

I'm trying to prove that for any algebra ${\cal A}$, $Aut({\cal A}) = \{a \in End({\cal A})\ |\ a([x, y]) = [a(x), a(y)], \forall x, y \in {\cal A}\}$ is a closed subgroup of $GL({\cal A})$.

I can prove that it is a subgroup just showing that $a\circ a^{'-1}$ is in $Aut({\cal A})$ which is direct computation. Nevertherless, I don't know how to show that thi group is closed. I've been thinking about proving that it is the isotropy group of $GL({\cal A})$, but I don't get it. I tried to impose that $[x, y]$ is the fixed point for the isotropy subgroup, but I just get:

$$a([x, y]) = a(x)a(y) - a(y)a(x) = xy - yx$$

But this means nothing because $a \in Aut({\cal A})$ is not imposing that $[x, y]$ is fixed.

How do I solve it?

Comment: First $a\in GL(A)$, not $End(A)$. Otherwise you'd have $0\in Aut(A)$. For the question, try to exhibit $Aut(A)$ as a zero set of polynomials

Comment: $a \in End({\cal A})$ because $a$ is a linear map $a: {\cal A} \rightarrow {\cal A}$, and I don't know what you mean by exhibit the automorphism group as a set of zero polynomials

Comment: You need yo specify that $a$ is invertible if that's what you want. A polynomial on a manifold $X$ is a smooth function. So the preimage of zero is closed