# What does 'closed group' mean?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

It's a basic question, but what do you mean when you say that a group or subgroup is closed? Is this that the action of the group over the corresponding space has always a norm less or equal than some number?

If you could give some examples too, it would be great.

Comment: It depends on context. A topological (sub)group can be closed if the underlying set is closed in the relevant topology. Or it could just be that the "closure" axiom holds, meaning that the product of two elements from the (sub)group is in the (sub)group.

Comment: I realized my comment was probably a bit hasty, so I edited.

Comment: It is in your best interest that you provide context for your question.

Comment: My context is in the way of proof this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3004488/closed-subgroup-of-gl-cal-a

Comment: In the context of Lie groups, it usually means the underying manifold is closed, i.e. compact and without boundary.

Comment: And how would you use that in order to solve the question in the following post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3004488/closed-subgroup-of-gl-cal-a?

Comment: The context you give seems to be another of your own questions — what is the *underlying* context of your questions?

Comment: The other one is my goal, and I thought that maybe the key was the idea of closed. That's all, I'm really stuck with it

Answer (score -2):

## Unless you are talking about topology or metric spaces, it usually corresponds to an operator on the group

To be closed under the operator means that if you use the operator on any two elements of the group or subgroup, the result is still contained in the group or subgroup. Note that this closure is required for by the definition of a group.